# SAML SSO - Request-URI Too Large

Tags: php, url, web, single-sign-on, server

I configured SAML SSO to my web application, it is working fine in localhost. But **NOT** **in** my **server** and getting error: 414 - Request-URI Too large as below.

Kindly help me to resolve my problem. Thanks in advance.

> ```
> **Request-URI Too Large**
>
> The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server.
> Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at xxx.xx.xx.xxx Port 80
> ```

Comment: If it is a SAMLResponse, use HTTP POST Binding instead of Redirect Binding because it includes assertions and becomes very large. If it is a short SAMLRequest, check whether the value is deflated, base64 and url-encoded properly first.

Answer (score 2):

The error suggests that you use the HTTP Redirect binding for SAML which passes SAML messages in HTTP query parameters. When the SAML messages are large the total total length of the URL+query parameters become very large (>2k characters) and may lead to this error. You should try and use a different SAML binding, e.g. SAML HTTP POST binding where parameters are passed in the HTTP POST body.